# Store table data in jsp variable

Tags: jsp

I have a table which prints the values from an object which is passed from the controller.

```
<c:forEach items="${dsr}" var="u">
    <tr>        
        <td>${u.task}</td>

        <td >${u.startTime}</td>
        <td>${u.endTime}</td>
        <td>${u.companyName}</td>
        <td>${u.status}</td> 

    <td><a href id="comp" data-id="${u.companyName}" data-target="#myId3" data-toggle="modal" aria-expanded="true">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

However I want to take the value from ${u.startTime} and assign it to jsp variable. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?:

```
<c:set var="startTime" scope="request" value="${u.startTime}"/>
<c:out value="${startTime}"/>
<%=request.getAttribute("startTime") %>
```

or

```
<c:set var="startTime" value="${u.startTime + 3434}"/>
<c:out value="${startTime}" />
<%=pageContext.getAttribute("startTime") %>
```

Comment: I am getting an error , time cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Oh, Maybe time is the same with some keyword, could you try with "startTime"

Comment: I am trying to print the variable startTime,  
<td ><%  out.println(startTime); %></td> But still getting the same error. Is this the correct way to print?

Comment: Actually I want to perform parsing operations on ${startTime} variable. So how can I do it?

Comment: Ok I see. you want to use variable in jSP to process. Let me update.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to take time in a variable and process it.